# Rewrite rule works in tester but not in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've made a `RewriteRule` for nice SEO url's. I've developed it on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ where it works as expected.

But when I implement it on my website it doesn't work and the server crashes.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+?(?=/))/(.+?)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [NC,L]
```

What I expect is:

**https://example.com/** > `https://example.com/index.php`

**https://example.com/page** > `https://example.com/index.php?a=page`

**https://example.com/page/categorie** > `https://example.com/index.php?a=page&b=categorie`

Comment: _Aside:_ Is the _positive lookahead_ required in the first rule? Since you are matching the slash anyway in the following part, the regex is only successful when the slash is present anyway, regardless of the _lookahead_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules will result in a rewrite loop, since the 2nd rule will match the rewritten URL-path, ie. `index.php`.

You could simply add an exception that precedes your existing rewrites:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

If the request matches `/index.php` (which it does after the first rewrite) then stop processing.

AND/OR, make your regex more restrictive (which would be recommended anyway). For example, instead of matching anything, ie. `.+`, match only word characters, eg. `\w+`. (Matches `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`). etc. Or match anything except slash or dot, eg. `[^/.]+`. You then wouldn't need to make the subpatterns non-greedy (in order to avoid matching the optional trailing slash).

**UPDATE:** If you are serving other static resources then you may need to perform a filesystem check to make sure that the request being rewritten does not already map to a file (or directory). This is common a common practise, however, it is relatively expensive (in terms of processing) and can often be avoided by making the regex more restrictive - as mentioned above.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Ignore (rewritten) requests for index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Ignore requests that map to files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite pretty URLs
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Note if you need to be able to accept hyphens (`-`) as part of the URL path segment then change `\w` to `[\w-]` - to add hyphens to the character class.

Comment: Thnks for your response, but it's not working... I've added the `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` between the `RewriteEngine On` and the first rule, but nothing changed

Comment: Have you made the regex more restrictive, as suggested? This will be mandatory if you are serving other static resources (images, CSS, JS, etc.) OR you will need to do a filesystem check (to check that the request does not already map to a file). But filesystem checks are relatively expensive, for what could be resolved by making the regex more restrictive. I'll update my answer with a note on the filesystem check...

Comment: I've also added a more complete example to my answer and additional notes.